# In a single script, how do I pass the output of an executed shell script, into another function?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to send an output of an executed shell script, to a log file.
However I want to put a timestamp at the start of the line for every output, so I created a function to do that.
But how do I pass the results of the executed shell script, into the function?

```
#This is a sample of the executed file testrun.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo "Script Executed."
```

```
#Actual script being run

#!/bin/bash

testlog="/home/usr/testlog.log"

log_to_file() {
    echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') $1" >> $testlog
}

sh /home/usr/testrun.sh >> log_to_file
```

If i were to log it normally, i would just do

```
sh /home/usr/testrun.sh >> $testlog
```

But how do I pass in the output of testrun.sh, into the function log_to_file, so that I can log the output to the file with the timestamp?

Comment: There's a linux command `ts` that will insert a timestamp at the beginning of its input. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course do a

```
log_to_file "$(sh /home/usr/testrun.sh)"
```

Of course if your `testrun.sh` produces more than one line of output, only the first one gets the timestamp as prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while read` loop to get each line into a variable that you can pass to `log_to_file`.

```
/home/usr/testrun.sh | while read -r line; do
    log_to_file "$line"
done >> "$testlog"
```

You could also use the `ts` command instead of your function

```
/home/usr/testrun.sh | ts >> "$testlog"
```